# What is the best way to access 2 different databases?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I have an application in nodejs. I want to use 2 MongoDb databases and consume data from them. Is it good practice to create 2 connects files?

Comment: A connection is a generally a pool of connections (and this is configurable). So, using a connection object to connect with more than one database should not be a problem. Have you tried? See [NodeJS - Connection Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/connection/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if your databases in two deferent clusters**
**Step 1**
create a connection.js file and put these code in it

```js
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient  // for first database
const mongoClient2 = require('mongodb').MongoClient // for second database
let db = null    // first database 
let db2 = null   // second database

module.exports = {
    // function to create connection to first database
connect : function (callback) {
    const uri = 'mongouri 1' // put your mongo uri here or in a .env file(recomended)
    const dbname = 'quizDb'

    mongoClient.connect(uri1, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return callback(err)
        db = data.db(dbname)
        callback()
    })
},
 // function to create connection to second database
connect2 : function (callback) {
    const uri2 = ' mongouri 2'  //  put your mongo uri here or in a .env file(recomended)
    const dbname = 'sample_mflix'
    mongoClient2.connect(uri2, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return callback()
        db2 = data.db(dbname)
        callback()
    })
},
get : () => db ,  // function to use first database 
get2 : () => db2  // function to use second database 
}
```

**Step 2**
in your server.js file put these

```js
// import your connection.js file
let db = require('./connection')

// conncting to first database 
db.connect((err) => err ? console.log(err) : console.log('database1 connected'))
// connecting to second database
db.connect2(err => err ? console.log(err) : console.log('database2 connected'))
```

**Step 3**
in any file where you want to acces data from defernt databases

```js
// import your connection.js 
const db = require('./connection')

// function to get data from first database 

function getOneQuiz(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.get().collection('quiz').findOne()
        .then(data => resolve(data))
        .catch(e => reject(e))
    })
}
// function to get data from second database
function getOneMovie(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     db.get2().collection('movies').findOne()
        .then(data => resolve(data))
        .catch(e => reject(e))
    })
)

//and call that function 
getOneMovie()
.then(movie=>console.log(movie))
.catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

**If your databases are in same cluster put these code in your connection.js file **

```js
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

let db = null          //databse 1
let db2 = null        //databse 2

module.exports = {
    connect: function (callback) {
        const dbname = 'quizDb'
        const dbname2 = 'newdb'
        mongoClient.connect(process.env.mongouri, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return callback(err)
            db = data.db(dbname)
            db2 = data.db(dbname2)
            callback()
        })
    },

    get: () => db,  // function to access database 1
    get2: () => db2    // function to access database 2

}
```

all other methods are same

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are stored in the same deployment, you should have one client instance and select the database as needed from that client.

If each database is for its own deployment, it would need its own client.

Comment: In MongoDb instances is the clusters?